# Locust Load Testing v2.20.1 self.stop() not working

Tags: locust

I'm using locust v2.20.1 and I would like to spawn 10 users but I only want each user to run the task once. I am not spawning workers (distrubuted runs) so using the self.environment.runner.quit() function stops the entire process and not that particular user.

I've noticed that there's a self.stop() function which should stop that task from running once again but when I run it, I get the following error: **locust.runners: While stopping users, we encountered a user that didn't have proper args <Greenlet "Greenlet-3" at 0x156f680cc20: _run>
**

It also doesn't stop the task from running. How can I spawn n users which only run the task once?

self.environment.runners.stop() - it stops the entire test (all users - i only want to stop a particular user once it reaches a point within the task)
self.stop() - does not work, it gives the following error: **locust.runners: While stopping users, we encountered a user that didn't have proper args <Greenlet "Greenlet-3" at 0x156f680cc20: _run>
**

Comment: User.stop() isnt meant to be called by the user itself, so that doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe try setting a long wait_time and use locust-plugins --iterations parameter? (assuming you are interested in unique users - if not then you dont even need the wait_time and can use a single user)

Comment: The problem is that --iterations closes the test once the task ran the specified number of times. I want each user to run the test once and it's not reliable because until the second, third and so on user spawns, the first user runs the task repeatedly and satisfies the iteration requirement and the test closes. I need multiple users because I am testing a closed api end point so my on_start function logs in and the task posts to the actual end-point.

Comment: In that case you need to set the long wait_time. Did you try that?